# My PC start although it is turned off

Tags: power, desktop-computer

My Problem:

- I shut my PC down
- Then I disconnect the plug
- Few hours later I reconnect the plug and the PC starts to boot for a short period and then turns off
- After that I can start the PC as usual and everything is OK

How can it happen that the PC starts when I reconnect the plug? (The electric current is somehow going through the PC, even though for a short period of time)

Can this behavior somehow destroy the PC?

**Update:**

- OS: Windows 8
- CPU: AMD
- Motherboard: MSI MS-7800
- BIOS: American Megatrends

I have checked it and it does not really boot, but the fan starts to rotate. There are few other sounds but the screen is black. It endures ca. 7 seconds, then it turns off.

Comment: How old is your PC; what is your operating system?

Comment: I would start with the power supply.  If you know this happens why disconnect the plug?

Comment: Either a "problem" with the power supply or some motherboard settings. Can you provide your motherboard model?

Comment: How far does it get in the boot process?

Comment: What Motherboard do you have? My old Asus motherboards would do this as a "pre-post", designed to perform some checks only once when it gained power, instead of every time the system booted up (and thus speeding up boot time)

Comment: @DarthAndroid I've updated the question.

Comment: I've had this before on my old Dell Dimension C521; the computer knows that you've pulled the plug and is conducting some checks, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Either you yourself, or someone else has changed your BIOS settings, those which are related to power and AC/power and stuff. You need to either find them yourself and correct them according to the manual of your motherboard, or you should provide us here, with the names of your mother board and your BIOS, so we can help you.

Comment: I've updated the question. So the BIOS is is the only one thing which can be? thank you

Comment: Not necessarily. There could be other items involved too, but they all must be related to your BIOS settings, like AC power back behaviour, alarm, resume behaviour, modem or sometimes ethernet power on settings. They all need to be checked. Plus if you assembled your PC yourself, or your PC is too old, you might want to check what is going on inside it.